# Automating a logical aggregation mapping function in python

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

I have one column named brand_name as:

```
Hum Iriga
Hum
Erel Methox
Erel neuro
Erel
```

Now I want to do logical aggregation such that Hum Iriga is same as Hum and Erel Methox and Erel neuro are same as Erel. One way is to define a mapping function like:

```
Mapping={

'EREL Methox':'EREL',
'HUM Iriga' :'HUM',
'EREL Neuro' : 'EREL',

}
```

f=lambda x: Mapping.get(x,x) ##x is the column(brand_name)

But now I do not want to hardcode it. I intent it to make it more automated, so that user do not have to specify the mapping. Can someone help me with this? I guess we have to use regular expressions to make this fully automated?

Answer (score 1):

The answer by `falsetru` is good, but there are also vectorized string functions in python which will likely be faster (and are generally nice to avoid having to `lambda` every time you want to do something similar.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'brand_names': ['Hum Iriga', 
                                   'Hum', 
                                   'Erel Methox', 
                                   'Erel neuro',
                                   'Erel'],
                   'other_column': range(5)})

df.brand_names.str.split().str[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to get only the first word from the string, you can use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and take the first splitted part:

```
>>> 'Hum Iriga'.split()
['Hum', 'Iriga']
>>> 'Hum Iriga'.split()[0]
'Hum'
```

---

```
f = lambda x: x.split()[0]

f = lambda x: x.split(None, 1)[0]  # 1: max split
```